# Creating music on specific key

Tags: scales

I want to know that in most DAWs we have tendency to make everything to create every note on C5 as DAWs like FL Studio create everything on C unless you change it manually or create it in piano roll.

Suppose i create a melody on D Scale now, should all instruments be created within the scale even if they sound ok ok Default C?

Comment: I don't think any of the DAWs I've used have any overall concept of the key the piece is in, or have any tendency to only create things in a certain key. Are you asking about Fruity Loops specifically?

Comment: Not specifically Fruity loops, let's suppose, i am creating a melody which is in a scale that doesn't have C in it. Now for the rest of instruments, including bassline, should i create them within the scale (not on C) even if they sound ok on C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FL Studio does not force you to use C scale. If you look at the piano roll you have full chromatic keyboard with all the notes. C notes are marked just for convenience as in the music C is usually used as point to which everything else relates. (BTW in piano roll menu in the top left corner there's useful Stamp tool that makes using scales much easier and you can start from any note).

It's hard to answer your question for 100% because it's very broad. I don't know what instruments/synths/samples you are using. Especially with samples the piano roll can be a bit confusing - for example you can use recorded sample of the G4 sound on the piano, but when the sample is loaded it is as default treated as C5 note. So, when you put D5 on piano roll it will be really the A4 sound on the piano.

Synths also have the possibility to be detuned (in EDM music detuning by less than semitone is often used to create "fat" sounds), so you cannot assume that playing note within the same scale on different intruments will sound well when played together.

Treat theory and scales as tool, not as the strict GO/NO GO rules, if something sounds OK for you then go for it.

Comment: Now this is what i was looking for. Thanks for explanation my answer was in last 3 sentences of your answer.